When to use InvocableVariable?
Are there any best practices as to when to use InvocableVariable? The official docs are not super helpful. It seems like the only reason to use it is when you need a custom request and/or response.
I'm asking because I've seen plenty of InvocableMethod + InvocableVariable implementations that just take an id and return a list of sObjects. And for these cases, I just don't see the benefit.
I'm simplifying a recent example that I found:
public class Request {
    @InvocableVariable
    public Id opportunityId;
}

public class Response {
    @InvocableVariable
    public List<Account> accounts;
}

@InvocableMethod
public static List<Response> getAccounts(List<Request> requests) {
    Id opportunityId = requests[0].opportunityId;

    Response res = new Response();

    res.accounts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE MainOpportunity__c = :opportunityId];

    return new List<Response> { res };
}

While I could just do something like this:
@InvocableMethod
public static List<Account> getAccounts(Id opportunityId) {
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE MainOpportunity__c = :opportunityId];
}

Is there anything I'm missing? Any big advantage the first solution has over the second?

You can refer to this blog may help you.

https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-invocable-apex-methods-a-complete-breakdown/


The key difference between the two you provided above: the first invocable method allows each call from the flow to pass in zero or more Accounts, while the second invocable method only accepts a single Account. The inputs and outputs from invocable methods are always lists to allow "flow bulkification", which allows the flow infrastructure to combine multiple operations into a single call.

You use @InvocableVariable when you have properties in a "custom" Apex class that should be accessible from the flow using the related invocable method's inputs and/or outputs.

The whole point of invocables is to provide a single bulk interface to all of the flow interviews. Similar to how SFDC bulkifies Get Records, Create Records, etc. elements.
It is "natural" to think that for Screen flows, there will be only one interview hence only a scalar input argument is needed as in your example two
@InvocableMethod
public static List<Account> getAccounts(Id opportunityId) {
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE MainOpportunity__c = 
   :opportunityId];
}

But even screen flow invocables can be called from the API (Actions API) and that interface demands bulkification
So, best practice using you example two would be
@InvocableMethod
public static List<List<Account>> getAccounts(Id[] opportunityIds) {
    .. code to get Accounts for each mainOpportunityId
       return a collection of account lists where 
             list[0] corresponds to opportunityIds[0]
             list[1] corresponds to opportunityIds[1]
             etc.
}

Personally, even if I think my Invocable is called only from a screen flow, I still adhere to the above model and put in code to throw an exception if opportunityIds.size() > 1 (especially if the bulkification logic gets complex because you have to allow for partial successes, etc.). This "protects" against usage in a record-triggered flow.
As for invocable variables, they are used when the invocable requires an ApexType as input and/or an ApexType as output (i.e., something other than a primitive, collection or SObject). Each property of the ApexType needs the InvocableVariable annotation to be visible to the Flow so the flow logic can pass / receive data.
